# JDBC - How to update record where date -1

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-update, prepared-statement

I have two tables with two columns for storing application settings in a SQL database. My question is how to update the record with changing the dCreateTime value into minus 1 day plus there are two table to calling where userID = atest211. My code seems not to be working.

My code:

```
public void getEmployeesFromDataBase() {
        try {
            String query = "update a set a.dCreateTime=a.dCreateTime-1 from tbet a, tuser b where a.iUserKey= b.iUserKey and b.sUserid = 'atest211' and a.dCreateTime> GETDATE()-5";
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                int EmpId = rs.getInt("iUserKey");
                String EmpName = rs.getString("sUserid");
                System.out.println(EmpId + "\t" + EmpName + "\t");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My updated code, it still is not working correctly

```
public void updateTableData() {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("update a set a.dCreateTime=a.dCreateTime-1 from tbet a, tuser b where a.iUserKey= b.iUserKey and b.sUserid = 'atest211' and a.dCreateTime> GETDATE()-5");
            pstmt.setString(1, "dCreateTime");
            pstmt.setString(2, "atest211");
            // To execute update query.
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            // Printing all records of user table after updating record.
            String query = "select * from tbet";
            // Get the contents of user table from DB
            ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(query);
            // Print the result untill all the records are printed
            // res.next() returns true if there is any next record else returns
            // false
            while (res.next()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s - %s - %s ", res.getString(1), res.getString(2),
                        res.getString(3), res.getString(4)));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why the selenium tag?

Comment: @Jens because im doing automation part for update record

Comment: But your question has nothing todo with selenium

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Standard SQL doesn't allow listing more then one table in the `from` clause of an `update` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @OldMcDonald , as i amend the code and it's working unfortunately there are some error during select statement while trying to retrieve the record out to check either the record has been updated , encounter error of : `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It resolved the error by adding `statement = connection.createStatement();`

Here's the code :

```
public void updateTableData() {
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            try { 
                //create calendar date -1 day
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 

                // preparing query to update record In db. 
                pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("update a set a.dCreateTime= ? from tbet a, tuser b where a.iUserKey= b.iUserKey and b.sUserid = ? and a.dCreateTime> GETDATE()-5");
                // Set name value which you wants to update. 
                pstmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime()));
                // Set id of record which you wants to update.
                pstmt.setString(2, "atest211");
                // To execute update query.
                pstmt.executeUpdate();

                // Printing all records of user table after updating record.
                String query = "select * from tbet where iUserKey=53298 ORDER BY tbet.dCreateTime desc";
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                // Get the contents of user table from DB
                ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(query);
                // Print the result untill all the records are printed
                // res.next() returns true if there is any next record else returns
                // false
                while (res.next()) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s - %s - %s ", res.getString(1), res.getString(2),
                            res.getString(3), res.getString(4)));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `result set` with an update, that is not possible.
Also, in your while loop, you are basically getting values from the database, not updating them.

If you want to update values, I advise you to use `PreparedStatement`.

If you want your code to work, try using `SELECT` instead of `UPDATE` in your query.

```
 String query = "SELECT a.dCreateTime FROM tbet a, tuser b WHERE a.iUserKey= b.iUserKey and b.sUserid = 'atest211' and a.dCreateTime> GETDATE()-5";
```

EDIT:
If you want to use an PreparedStatement, try something like this

```
// create the preparedstatement
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
  "UPDATE yourTable SET title = ?, author = ? WHERE id = ?");

ps.setString(1,title);
ps.setString(2,author);
ps.setInt(3,id);

//execute the upate
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```

Comment: Try using PreparedStatements then, you can't update with ResultSets. Read the offical docu for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: i did some research on PreparedStatement however i have no clue how to do it , any idea for this  ? Thanks you

Comment: I've edited my post to include a prepared statement.

Comment: Hi , Please have a look on my edit part . i have amend the code but still not working .

Answer (score 1):

You need the update ... join .. set .. where Syntax:

```
       String query = "update a join b on a.iUserKey= b.iUserKey set a.dCreateTime=a.dCreateTime-1  where b.sUserid = 'atest211' and a.dCreateTime> GETDATE()-5";
```

Next is you have to use `statement.execute(query);` instead of using `executeQuery(query)`.
That method do not return an resultset ....

Also you should read about SQL injection and using prepared Statements.